# Excel - Conditional Formatting with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I'm not really sure the best way to go about this. I'm trying to highlight cells if two conditions are met: If the cells do not contain the word "Null" and if Cell O2<>P2 (or do not format if O2=P2). I've tried a few different variations, but here's what my code (that's not working) looks like at the moment.

`=NOT(OR("Null",O2=P2))`

I already have conditional formatting for when O2=P2 and when a cell contains "Null". Now, I just need to highlight the other ones.

Comment: What cells are getting this conditional formatting? Do the "Null" cells just contain "Null", or could there be other surrounding text, e.g. "foo Null bar"?

Comment: `"Null"` on its own cannot return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Try: =AND(A1<>"Null", $O$2<>$P$2)` (assuming the first cell that should be formatted is `A1`)

Comment: Cells in Row P (starting with 2 as row 1 is for my titles) are being formatted and the ones that have "Null" just say Null. I never thought to try the AND.

The code works! Here it is:
`=AND(P2<>"Null",O2<>P2)`

Comment: Btw @cybernetic.nomad do you want to post the answer to the question, since you gave me the inspiration or do you want me to self answer and link to your comment or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Null"` on its own cannot return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Try:

```
 =AND(P2<>"Null", O2<>P2)
```

(based on your comment that cells in column `P` are to be formatted)